# Docker-compose run service if another service status is 0 (success)

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, dockerfile, build-automation

I am pretty new to Docker and Docker compose.

I want to use docker compose to test my project and publish it if tests are ok. If tests are failed, it should not publish the app at all.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
  test:
    build: 
      context: .    
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.tests
    links:
      - mongodb
  publish:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.publish
  ?? # I want to say here that publish step is dependent to test.
```

After that, in my `testAndPublish.sh` file, I would like to say:

```
  docker-compose up

  if [ $? = 0 ]; then  # If all the services succeed
      ....
  else
      ....
  fi
```

So if test or publish steps are failed, I am not going to push it.

How can I build step like processes in docker-compose?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do everything with `docker-compose` which is the wrong way around.

When it comes to CI (f.e. Travis or CircleCI) I always make my workflow as follows:

- let's say you have a `web` node and `database` node
- In `travis.yml` or `circle.yml` at the `install` step I always put things like f.e. `docker-compose run web npm install` and others
- at the `test` step I would put `docker-compose run web npm test` or something similar like `docker-compose run web my-test-script.sh`, that way you'll know that the tests will run in the declared docker environment, if they fail this step fails and the whole test step in the CI fails which is desired
- at the `deploy` step I would run some `deploy.sh` script which will build the image from Dockerfile (the one that `web` uses) and push it for example to Docker Hub.

This way your CI test routine still depends on specific Docker environment but the deploy push (which doesn't need Docker) is kept separately from the application which makes it more convinient imho.